# Editing Gradle Init script within IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I'm working a few [Gradle Initialization Scripts](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html) to help automate some tasks.  To get it working in IntelliJ IDEA, I added a module to my project that points to my `~/.gradle/init.d` folder.  However there are a few problems.

Intellisense is not working for most elements of the script.  For example:

```
allprojects {
    task hello{
        doLast {
            println("hello world")
        }
    }
}
```

The tokens "allprojects", "task", "doLast" are all not recognized by the IDE and are grey and underlined.  It suggests that the script is wrong, but it works fine.

Also, breakpoints are ignored when running a gradle task as debug.

Is there a better way to develop these scripts in IntelliJ?

Comment: What version of IintelliJ is used?

Comment: The latest Ultimate edition.